# ViewModel. Load LINQ query to view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

Im using EF 6 and I need a LINQ query to fetch all the data to my ViewModel.
Every Event has a status (one to one)
There are not FK in tables

I want do display something like that:

```
EventID   EventStatusID   Name      EventDate   EventDesc    
99        1               Allowed   2000-1-1    Music festival
```

ViewModel class:

```
public class EventVM : Event
{
    public EventStatus EStatus { get; set; }
}
```

Event class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Event
{
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public int EventStatusID { get; set; }
    public string EventNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    public string EventDesc { get; set; }
}
```

Event status class:

```
[Serializable]
public class EventStatus
{
    public int EventStatusID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Desc{ get; set; }
}
```

Event table:

```
dbo.Event

    Column name     Type       Allow nulls
PK  Eventid         int        no
    Eventstatusid   int        no
    Eventnumber     nvarchar   no
    Eventdate       date       no
    Eventdesc       nvarchar   no
```

EventStatus table:

```
dbo.EventStatus

    Column name     Type       Allow nulls
PK  Eventstatusid   int        no
    Desc            nvarchar   no
    Name            nvarchar   no
```

I stucked in this moment :

```
            var viewModel =
           (from ev in db.Events
            join evs in db.EventStatus on ev.EventStatusID equals evs.EventStatusID
            where ev.EventStatusID == id

            select new EventVM
            {
                EventID = ev.EventID
            }).First();
```

with error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'The entity or complex type 'ModelEvent.EntityFramework.Concrete.EventVM' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.'

I cant change View Model, i have to use this one

Comment: Just select to anonymous type and then create a model.

Comment: Or make the view model class not inherit from `Event`

Answer (score 0):

You need to *create model* or use *anonymous type* to gather data from DB (don't forget to use `ToList()` to actually gather data), and then map it's *properties* to *properties* of a `EventVM`. You are getting this error, because `EF` is unable to properly create instance of `EventVM`.